# What are good abilities and weapons against metal slimes?

Tags: dragon-quest-of-the-stars

Just like in the whole Dragon Quest series, in Dragon Quest of the Stars the best way to gain experience is to defeat metal slimes in different forms. However, they are notoriously hard to defeat because a lot of attacks and spells do not do any damage. A lot of my helpers have a *Metal Slime Sword/Spear/Bow*, are they any good in defeating them? What abilities are good against it?

I do have a weapon with *Metal Blow*, and that works quite well (it also states that in the description). Once I saw a helper with the ability Metallurgy, but not against metal slimes. I could not find the description of this ability, because I do not have it yet.

So I am looking a bit for best strategies to defeat metal slimes, but to narrow it down I would like to know which weapons and abilities are performing well on metal slimes.

Answer (score -1):

Metal Slime Axe is great for king slimes. I also like the metal slime boomerang and bow since they can hit multiple times, you just can't direct them. Also the boomerang seems to crit more than normal, which would help with defeating enemies.